# Does the ability or the ability slot get passed down when breeding?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

When breeding in Gen 6, do the abilities themselves have the possibility of being passed down, or do the slots themselves get passed?

Example:
[Ninjask](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/291.shtml) can have the ability `Speed Boost` naturally. [Venipede](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/543.shtml) can have `Speed Boost` as a hidden ability.

Can `Speed Boost` be passed down?

EDIT: This question is different from [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219329) question, as that questions asks if you can breed a hidden ability from two parents who don't have a hidden ability, while my question is about whether the ability itself (`Speed Boost`) gets passed down during breeding, or if the ability slot gets passed down ("the child will have its hidden ability, whatever that is").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When breeding, it tends to work by 'slot'. *However* the 'slots' only tend to come into play when the hatched pokemons abilities differ from their more evolved parents (Nincada's 'slot1' *Compound Eyes* becomes Ninjask's 'slot1' *Speed Boost*). In any breeding pair where a ditto is not present, it is only the female that passes down their ability. If we look at your proposed situation:

```
            Slot1      | Slot2 | Hidden Ability
Ninjask:  Speed Boost  |  N/A  | Infiltrator
Venipede: Poison Point | Swarm | Speed Boost
```

- A **female Ninjask** (Or a male if bred with a Ditto) with *Speed Boost* will *always* pass down the slot 1 ability (Which would be Compound Eyes on the hatched Nincada).
- A **female Ninjask** with *Infiltrator* will have an 80% to pass down the hidden ability (Nincada hatches with Run Away). The remaining 20% would get the slot1 ability.
- A **male Ninjask** with *Infiltrator* has a 20% chance to pass it down if bred with a Ditto (The remaining 80% would get the slot1).
- A **female Venipede** with *Poison Point* will pass down the slot1 ability 80% of the time (the remaining 20% would hatch with slot2).
- A **female Venipede** with *Swarm* will pass down the slot2 ability 80% of the time (the remaining 20% would hatch with slot1).
- A **female Venipede** with *Speed Boost* will have an 80% chance to pass down the hidden ability. The remainder would be divided equally (10% slot1, 10% slot2).
- A **male Venipede** with *Poison Point* or *Swarm* when bred with a Ditto has a 50% chance to for the egg to hatch with a slot1 ability, and 50% chance for slot2
- A **male Venipede** with *Speed Boost* has a 20% chance to pass it down if bred with a Ditto. The remainder would be divided equally (40% slot1, 40% slot2).

At no point in the various pairings does the male have much say in what ability gets passed down (unless the male (or genderless) is bred with a Ditto) it does not matter if the male has a hidden ability, or an ability that matches the name of one of the female's abilities.

For further reading, you can look up breeding on [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/games/breed.shtml) (scroll down to the "Standard Abilities" and "Hidden Abilities" headings) or on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding#Inheriting_Abilities).